# JavaScriptCore Portability

Tags: javascript, ios, webkit, javascriptcore

I'm considering embedding JavaScriptCore in an application. I'm curious as to how portable it is? Ideally I'd like it to run on Linux, Windows & OSX as well as Android and iOS. Naturally OSX and iOS shouldn't be a problem, what about the remainder?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is actually pretty easy to compile... even I have done it, lol.  Just check it out via [SVN as part of the webkit source code](http://trac.webkit.org/wiki/JSC) and from there it is just a matter of your options at compile-time that will determine how portable it is...  you can make it a standalone binary to run javascript against, or include the headers,etc in your project - for built-in JS magic.  One thing, unless you want the whole Webkit source tree, which is enormous, you might want to just download the JavascriptCore part.  Up to you.. there is some interesting stuff in the rest of the WK tree, although.